# Fine-tuning a deep neural network in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to partially fine-tune a pre-trained deep neural network in Tensorflow (as in, load weights for all layers but only update weights on higher level layers).

Is there any method in Tensorflow that allows the selection of variables that should be changed and those that should be kept the same?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create an optimizer (e.g. [`tf.train.AdagradOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#AdagradOptimizer)) to train your model, you can pass an explicit `var_list=[...]` argument to the [`Optimizer.minimize()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.minimize) method. (If you don't specify this list, it will default to containing all of the variables in [`tf.trainable_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#trainable_variables).)

For example, depending on your model, you might be able to use the names of your variables to define the list of variables to be optimized:

```
# Assuming all variables to be fine-tuned have a name that starts with
# "layer17/".
opt_vars = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name.startswith("layer17/")]

train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=opt_vars)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: How can we do it in TFLearn